# Sly vertical scroller, add autoplay?

Tags: javascript, sly-scroller

Using sly vertical scroller how is it possible to add autoplay?
So it starts moving the slides.

Example: `http://jsfiddle.net/9dJfQ/`

```
// Call Sly on frame
    $frame.sly({
        horizontal: 1,
        itemNav: 'basic',
        smart: 0,
        scrollBy: 1,
        mouseDragging: 1,
        swingSpeed: 0.2,
        scrollBar: $wrap.find('.hsscrollbar'),
        dragHandle: 1,
        clickBar: 1,
        elasticBounds: 1,
        speed: 600,
        startAt: 0,                 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to initialization options:

```
cycleBy: 'items',
cycleInterval: 1500,  // Cycle interval
pauseOnHover: true,
startPaused:   false
```

More info in the docs on Github: https://github.com/darsain/sly/blob/master/docs/Options.md